# How to find out which DLLs another EXE/DLL depend on via dynamic runtime loading?

Tags: dll, dependencies, reverse-engineering, analysis, exe

I've tried Dependency Walker, but when I run the exe in profile, Dependency Walker froze.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) shows all DLLs loaded by application.

Comment: @JayXon: Just loaded. By anything.

Answer (score -1):

Loaded dll in an exe are located in the Data Directory-Import Table section.
Loading the executable in [studPE](http://www.google.com/search?q=studpe) and looking at the "functions" tab will give you the list of dlls.

You could also load the program in OllyDbg and press Alt+E (or menu view->executable modules) to see a list of dll's